# GWT + JDO = ClassCastException

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo, gwt-rpc

I am using GWT + Google App Engine and JDO to store objects in the App Engine datastore.

I create the object below on the client-side via web interface and pass it via RemoteProcedureCall to the server where it shall be stored into the Google App Engine datastore. The RPC works fine as the object is successfully transmitted to the server. But when I call pm.makePersistent(myCustomObject) at the server, it crashes with the error-log below:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.datanucleus.identity.IdentityReference cannot be cast to org.datanucleus.identity.OID

**The object to be stored:**

```
package at.fhooe.mc.shared;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.jdo.annotations.EmbeddedOnly;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Extension;
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable;

@PersistenceCapable
public class Questionnaire implements IsSerializable {

// ************************************
// * MEMBER VARIABLES
// ************************************

/**
 * Unique identifier of the questionnaire. This Id is used as primary key in
 * the datastore.
 */
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
@Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")
String key;

/**
 * Title of the questionnaire.
 */
private String m_title;

/**
 * List of the actual questions in the questionnaire.
 */
@Persistent
private List<Question> m_questions;

// ************************************
// * CONSTRUCTOR
// ************************************

/**
 * Constructor.
 */
public Questionnaire() {
    m_questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
}

/**
 * Constructor.
 * 
 * @param _title
 *            Title of the questionnaire.
 */
public Questionnaire(String _title) {
    m_title = _title;
    m_questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
}

// ************************************
// * GETTERS / SETTERS
// ************************************

/**
 * Gets the Id of the question. This Id is also used as primary key in the
 * datastore.
 * 
 * @return Id the questionnaire.
 */
public String getId() {
    return key;
}

/**
 * Gets the title of the questionnaire.
 * 
 * @return Title of the questionnaire as string.
 */
public String getTitle() {
    return m_title;
}

/**
 * Sets the title of the questionnaire.
 * 
 * @param _title
 *            Title of the questionnaire.
 */
public void setTitle(String _title) {
    m_title = _title;
}

/**
 * Gets all available questions of the questionnaire.
 * 
 * @return All available questions of the questionnaire.
 */
public List<Question> getQuestions() {
    return m_questions;
}

/**
 * Adds a question to the questionnaire.
 * 
 * @param _question
 *            The question to be added.
 */
public void addQuestion(Question _question) {

    m_questions.add(_question);

}

// ************************************
// * INNER CLASS
// ************************************

/**
 * This class represents a single question of a questionnaire. It consists
 * of the actual question-text and the answer-type.
 */
@PersistenceCapable
@EmbeddedOnly
public static class Question implements IsSerializable {

    /**
     * Defines the answer-type of the question (e.g.: yes-or-no,
     * likert-scale, etc).
     */
    public enum AnswerType {

        YES_OR_NO("yes_or_no"), LIKERT("likert");

        private String stringValue;

        private AnswerType(String _stringValue) {
            stringValue = _stringValue;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return stringValue;
        }
    }

    public Question() {

    }

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * 
     * @param _text
     *            The actual question as String.
     * @param _answerType
     *            The answertype as enum.
     * @param _answer
     *            The user-answer.
     */
    public Question(String _text, AnswerType _answerType, int _answer) {
        m_text = _text;
        m_answerType = _answerType;
        m_answer = _answer;
    }

    /**
     * The selected answer-type of the question.
     */
    @Persistent
    private AnswerType m_answerType;

    /**
     * The actual question as string.
     */
    @Persistent
    private String m_text;

    /**
     * The actual answer to the question.
     */
    @Persistent
    private int m_answer;

}

}
```

**The resulting stacktrace:**

```
javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract void at.fhooe.mc.client.PushMessageService.sendMessages(at.fhooe.mc.shared.Questionnaire)' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.datanucleus.identity.IdentityReference cannot be cast to org.datanucleus.identity.OID
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:409)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.datanucleus.identity.IdentityReference cannot be cast to org.datanucleus.identity.OID
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.extractChildKey(EntityUtils.java:915)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.StoreFieldManager.getDatastoreObjectForCollection(StoreFieldManager.java:983)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.StoreFieldManager.storeRelations(StoreFieldManager.java:877)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObjectsInternal(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:367)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:218)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.internalMakePersistent(JDOStateManager.java:2381)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.makePersistent(JDOStateManager.java:2357)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObjectInternal(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1896)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObjectWork(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1745)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1602)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:731)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:756)
at at.fhooe.mc.server.PushMessageServiceImpl.sendMessages(PushMessageServiceImpl.java:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
... 38 more
```

Looking forward to seeing your helpful answers!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so what state (JDOHelper.getObjectState) is the object in when you call makePersistent?